# Flutter: Access Process stdout and stream to StreamBuilder widget

Tags: flutter, dart, process

I want to be able to start a process using `await Process.start()` and be able to access the stdout during the execution of the process and send the output to a StreamBuilder widget.

StreamBuilder Widget

```dart
StreamBuilder(
          stream: snapshot.data,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot stream) {
            print('Connection State: ${stream.connectionState}');
            switch (stream.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.done:
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: controller,
                    reverse: true,
                    child: Text(
                      executionOutput,
                    ));
              default:
                executionOutput += '\n${stream.data}';
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                    controller: controller,
                    reverse: true,
                    child: Text(
                      executionOutput,
                    ));
```

Here is my stream code I wanted to check the stdout every second until the process finishes

```dart
Stream getOutput() async* {
    var p = await Process.start('python.exe', ['streamData.py']);

    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      yield p.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).toString();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yield*` to delegate the stream to another stream.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {
  getOutput().listen(print);
}

Stream getOutput() async* {
  var p = await Process.start('tail', ['-f', '/path/to/log']);
  yield* p.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder);
}
```